# Where can I find stimuli for steady-state visually-evoked potentials?

Tags: methodology, vision, evoked-potentials

I am a student working on a project which deals with Steady State Visually-Evoked Potentials (SSVEP) Stimuator. Does anybody know where can I find stimuli (checkerboard or single graphic) as a video file? It's very difficult to find these files on the Internet. I am not allowed to use videos from youtube.

Comment: What is SSVEP and why can't you create the stimuli yourself?

Comment: steady state evoke potentials. For evoke this potentils you need to see a special stimuli like a flickering checkerboard or single graphics. Does anybody know where can I find them?

Comment: What system are you using? For example, the people from Espion (a widely applied ERG/VEP system) are very kind folks that are always more than willing to help out (needless to say, as long as you are using their system :-)

Answer (score 3):

Researchers are often willing to share their stimuli. If you know of a paper that uses the same kind of stimuli that you want to use, you could try emailing the authors. A friendly request with a brief explanation of why you want the stimuli usually works.

Comment: I disagree. It's certainly not the ideal answer to the question but it is an answer. Contacting people who have used the stimuli before is a really common way to solve exactly the problem that the question poses (how do I find stimuli that aren't readily available on the web?).

Comment: I agree with @Josh here. Cognitive scientists frequently don't host these anywhere, so telling the author to use email is just instructing them on common practice.